# Unable to access .mdf file after installing application using Visual Studio setup project

Tags: wpf, installation, setup-project

I have created a WPF application. I am using Visual Studio setup project to create application setup.

In my application, I have a local database which is located in project folder (Application folder). When I install the application to any other drive than C: drive (operating system drive), then it is working fine. But when I install the application to the `C:` drive, then my application is not able to access the database file. Also, when I attach the database to SQL Server Management Studio, it is attaching as readonly:

[image]

Also, I viewed the Eventviewer and I find this error:

[image]

I tried adding the `.mdf` file to the `Programdata` folder but still the issue is not resolved. I am aware that it is a permission related issue. But is there any way to resolve this issue using Visual Studio setup project?

Comment: A `.mdf` file is a **SQL Server** database file - so in order to use it, you **must have** SQL Server Express installed on that machine. Are you installing this dependency with your application??

Comment: @marc_s: Yes, I have added prerequisites with the application. Also, I mentioned that I am able to run the application as expected to any other drive other than operating system drive (C drive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Installer class and write below code in Commit method.
You have to give the read/write permission to mdf file.
You can give this by below line of code; make sure that your installation directory also has the write permission.

```
string directoryName = @"C:\rnd\ConsoleApplication16\ConsoleApplication16\";
        string SharedCachePath = @"C:\rnd\ConsoleApplication16\ConsoleApplication16\xyz.mdf";
        var fs = File.GetAccessControl(directoryName);
            fs.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, true);
            File.SetAccessControl(SharedCachePath, fs);
```

you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38357038/c-sharp-setup-project-custom-action-to-save-the-installation-directory-to-custom) for installer class use
Hopefully this will work and resolve your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the great help. I am able to resolve the issue. I made a small change by providing access the folder containing my Database files as I have separate folder for database files. :)